# Not getting paypal post response in android mobile browsers

Tags: php, paypal

This is my code.I got response in desktop browsers but not getting in android mobile browsers.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo base_url().'cancel'?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url().'success'?>">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show..?

Comment: I am working with codeingiter framework